# Create polygon from routeboxer boxes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-maps, gis, routeboxer

I am trying to create a polygon from the boxes i obtain from the routeboxer algorithm. I am new to GIS and was looking for some pointers. I am also looking at the JSTS library but I think it can only give me intersections. I couldn't find much documentation anywhere.

Is there a way I can combine the boxes to form a polygon so a single `$within` query can do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a computational geometry problem and you can use the algorithm described [here](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/Papers/OrthoConnect.pdf).

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746284/merging-multiple-adjacent-rectangles-into-one-polygon)!